# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject for negative integer is zero Android

Tags: android, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize a Json to an object. In the Json there is `"PageNumber": -1` but, after deserializing I am always getting `PageNumber = 0`. I noticed all negative values will be converted to zeros.

Is there any way to get negative integers after deserializing?

Json:

```
{
  "Pages": [
    {
      "A": [
        {
          "B": [
            {
              "numberone": -1,
              "numbertwo": -1          
            },
            {
              "numberone": -1,
              "numbertwo": -1 
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After deserializing I checked the `list<B>`:

```
numberone = 0 and numbertwo = 0
```

Comment: Can you please post your json and a raw output of the deserialized object?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone has same problem, I fixed it like this:

```
            var handleNegativeValues = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal
            };

            //Deserialize from json to class object
            MyClass myObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCLass>(await _mHttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), handleNegativeValues);
```

This is in C# Xamarin